# Is the episode 6 history of Justy Ueki Tylor in "Irresponsible Galaxy" canon?

Tags: the-irresponsible-captain-tylor, the-irresponsible-galaxy-tylor

In episode 6 of *The Irresponsible Galaxy Tylor*, a narrator tells the story of Justy Ueki Tylor. He begins by describing the events of *The Irresponsible Captain Tylor*, before stating:

> […] He returned Goza XV to Raalgon, and brough about a temporary peace.
>
> However … Ceasefires are easily broken. Tylor and Ru Baraba Dom had a battle for control of the galaxy. Tylor won the battle completely, but the Grand Duchy of Ashuran conquered the galaxy. Raalgon and the United Planets put together a joint front, and in the final battle with Ashura, used their ultimate weapon, Suou to win, and bring about eternal piece. Tyler [sic] became president of the Raalgon Republic!
>
> Tylor declared war on the United Planets, and had a final battle with Makoto Yamamoto. Tylor won, uniting the galaxy, and became the pan-galactic emperor! Ensured by Tylor's success, the Pan-Galactic Empire flourished. But now, humanity is in its twilight on the sidereal mega-structure.

[Text taken from the current version of the Crunchyroll subtitles. There may be mistakes: I hear what appears to be ゴザ十六世 in the audio, rather than ゴザ十五世. The narrator is also clearly referring to Azalyn, who is Goza XVI. Paragraph breaks are my own.]

Did the events described here actually happen in the *Irresponsible Captain Tylor* franchise, or was this all something that the narrator made up (or alternatively, something that was made-up for this spin-off)? Such events do not seem to happen in the OVA, and I also cannot find any reference to a confrontation with Ru Baraba Dom on [his wiki page](http://tylor.wikia.com/wiki/Ru_Baraba_Dom). But it seems possible that there may be light novel content that non-Japanese fans may be unaware of.

Comment: The light novels went well beyond what the anime series and OVA covered, and at least come close to what was described. According to The Irresponsible Captain Tylor OVA liner notes the Duchy of Ashran (which appears in the OVA) does try to take over the galaxy with a super weapon, the Raalgon Empire becomes the Raalgon Republic and eventually merges with the United Planets to form Pan-Galactic Republic. One of the titles of the light novels is The Irresponsible President Tylor (though I had always assumed that meant he became president of the United Planets).